# SAPUI5 SmartVariantManagement isn't working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to implement a SAPUI5 App and I want to use the SmartVariantManagement.

I've implemented my app based on the following sample:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar.example2/code

I know that I have to set the ID of the SmartVariantManagement for the SmartFilterBar as well as the SmartTable.
The problem is, that my FilterBar and the Table are wrapped inside different Fragement so I cannot refer to that ID.

So I tried to set the ID of the SmartVariant during runtime with the method "setSmartVariant" like this:

```
var oSmartVariantManagement = this.getView().byId("SmartVariantManagement");
oSmartFilterBar.setSmartVariant(oSmartVariantManagement.getId());
```

I am doing this in the init event of the filterBar but somehow it is not working and the Smart Variant doens't show any value.

Does anyone know if I have to set the ID in a different event?